# I'm trying to pick a stepper motor and motor driver. Are these compatible? (TMC2130 & ROB-13656‎)

Tags: current, motor, stepper-motor, driver

I'm using stepper motor for an application that requires the motor to be extremely silent. (not 3D printing) So I found out that the TMC2130 driver (or TMC2100) does just that. In my research of specs between drivers and motors I've gotten pretty confused. I've come down to using the [TMC2130](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet.pdf) to drive a [Sparkfun ROB-13656](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13656)‎ stepper motor. Before I purchase I want to make sure the voltage and current ratings of both will work together.

The TMC2130 says it supports stepper motors up to 2.0A coil current (2.5A peak). The ROB-13656 says 2.0A/phase. Is that the same thing as coil current?

The TMC2130 says it has a voltage range of 4.75-46V DC. And the ROB-13656 says Voltage: 3.2V. I know these specs don't correlate since the driver is monitoring the current, but I still don't really understand how they relate to each other.

Comment: There are many existing questions here on stepper motor driving; see the sidebar at right.  Typically with a current mode driver you want the driver voltage to be several times the coil ohmic voltage.  If you really need silence, a stepper may not be the right motor technology; generally they are used for simplicity, not because they are a very good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the pair will work well together.
You don't need to worry about the 3.2 V specified for the stepper motor since the TMC2130 is a switching current regulator. You can expect the motor to get quite warm in operation as the windings will dissipate a bit over 5 W averaged together at 2 A peak drive.
The stepper motor at 125 oz/in is a rather beefy unit but if you are going to be using high micro step ratios then you can expect to see only a fraction of this torque around the zero crossings.